# jquery -preload single large animated gif

Tags: jquery, gif, preload

I have a large animated gif, I would like to preload this with jquery will a single still as a placeholder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you could do an ajax-preload-call before $(document).ready and get the file. create a new "image-object" and set the file to "image-object.src"